# Custom DateTime, customising the date format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am trying to get a custom date for a folder renaming.

Is there by any chance a way to display todays date in this format ex: 20130629

Thanks

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You call `DateTime.ToString` with a custom format. Now, what have you tried and what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

[**MSDN**: Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: I would suggest explicitly using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, to avoid using the current culture's calendar.

Answer (score 0):

simply use: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`